# Migrate multiple gitlab repositories to github - how to do it all at once (instead of manually)

Tags: git, github, gitlab, migration, repository

I have 45 projects/repositories on Gitlab. I want to move it to my Github.

I know there is a way to do it on the UI one by one by import repository.

But how to do it all at once?

Comment: Do you want to do it through the UI (which I don't think is possible), or is a command OK?

Comment: Commands will be fine. Whichever works. I am just looking for a solution and to understand how I can migrate these repos.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with gitlab—do these repositories exist as "folders" in your computer, locally?

Comment: The concept of repositories remain the same as in github and gitlab. But to store them as folders on my computer locally, I need to clone each of these repositories from gitlab.

Comment: You can `git clone --mirror` the repository from GitLab and then `git push --mirror` the cloned commits-and-names to GitHub. Note, however, that the issues and comments, pull-or-merge-requests, etc., on these hosting sites and systems are stored outside the repository, so you can't copy those this way.

Comment: But then I have to do it one by one for each, right?

Comment: I'm not sure there is way you can migrate several repositories at once, as firstly you will have to create them on Github, I believe (all 45+). Then you can set up 1 local Git repository with all old Gitlab and new Github remotes added. After that your can write simple shell script to push all commits from each Gitlab repo to corresponding Github repo by mask. This may partly reduce pain, but in case you're using public tools such Github/Bitbucket don't thinks there is other opportunity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a python based solution assuming we are referencing only repos inside your projects list (not within sub-groups, though this can be modified to work for that case).

These steps will walk you through the hard part of this problem, getting the repositories to exist on GitHub (with added bonus of copying descriptions over and matching the public/private settings). To do this, you will have to use the GitHub API or create them manually.

Prereqs:

- setup [Gitlab API Token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#create-a-personal-access-token)
- setup [GitHub API Token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)

This will use the GitLab list projects [GET request](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects). Also, it will repeatedly use the GitHub create repo [POST request](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos#create-a-repository-for-the-authenticated-user). Once you run this (personally tested), you can use the list of repos output at the end and write some simple bash to iterate over them cloning each repository, [adding a git remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote), then pushing to the remote. Alternatively, you could use the `--mirror` option above. Regardless, options abound at this point.

```py
GITLAB_USERNAME = "<user>"
GITHUB_USERNAME = "<user>"

GITLAB_TOKEN = "<token>"
GITHUB_TOKEN = "<token>"

import requests
import json

# get the list of repos from gitlab
x = requests.get( \
    url='https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/{user}/projects'.format(user=GITLAB_USERNAME), \
    headers={'PRIVATE-TOKEN': GITLAB_TOKEN})
# print the response code (200 is success)
print(x)

repo_names = []
# iterate the repos 1 by 1
for repo in json.loads(x.content):
    # print out repo details to see functioning
    print('Name:', repo['name'])
    print('Description:', repo['description'])
    print('Visibility:', repo['visibility'])
    print('ssh_url_to_repo:', repo['ssh_url_to_repo'])

    repo_names.append(repo['name'])

    # create the repo on GitHub with the name, description, and private/public
    y = requests.post( \
        url='https://api.github.com/user/repos', \
        headers={'Accept': 'application/vnd.github+json', 'Authorization': 'token {token}'.format(token=GITHUB_TOKEN)}, \
        json={'name': repo['name'], 'description': repo['description'], 'private': repo['visibility']=='private'})
    # print the response code (201 is created [success])
    print(y)
    print('')

# print the list of repos for reference
for name in repo_names:
    print(name)
```

Comment: So, this python code you shared basically would bring all the repo names from gitlab and create the same name repos in github, right?

Comment: Yes. Note that it won't copy the repo contents (the new ones will be empty), but that could be a more simple bash loop. You can comment out the `y = ...` section to see it accessing the gitlqb repos without creating anything.

Comment: @LearnerJS I have used dcat52's answer to extend his script and add everything here:
https://github.com/gitshashwat/common_scripts/tree/main/gitlab_to_github_migration

Comment: Thank you folks. @dcat52 add this link with the transfering script in the answer too.